# Google Apps Marketplace SDK - Admin Config Url

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I created a test APP and installed it on my domain.  I don't see a link for the Admin Config Url anywhere in my domain's console.  If I go to the Settings for my app it just has the Universal navigation links.

The Setup Url also doesn't get called when adding the app to my domain.

Do these settings still do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  The link has to end in .com (probably other extensions work as well).  I was using localhost and the link wouldn't appear.

Comment: Thanks much - I was scratching my head trying to find my localhost links in my test app.  Changed to "real" urls and it showed.  Really annoying behavior there, especially with no documentation. Wish they'd allow localhost, they do for all the other URLs.